# Enable Button when mat-radio-button is checked

Tags: angular, typescript

I want button enable when mat-radio-button is checked. But it not unable when I checked it. I dont know where is the problem.Bellow I provide code and demo for your reference.
This [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-1unx3w) for your reference

**HTML**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngStyle]="{'display': 'none'}"> No. </th>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                    <mat-radio-button
                        (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" 
                        (change)="$event ? selection.select(row) : null"
                        [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
                    </mat-radio-button>
                </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="No">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.rowspan]="2">No</th>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Header row first group -->

  <!-- Header row second group -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="header-row-second-group">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="2"> Second group </th>
  </ng-container>



  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="['No', 'header-row-second-group']"></tr>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>

<button mat-raised-button color="accent" [disabled]="!selectedRow" (click)="deleteUser()">Delete User</button>
```

**Component**

```
 selectedRow: any;
  selection = new SelectionModel<PeriodicElement>(true, []);
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

  deleteUser(){
    console.log(this.selectedRow)
  }
}
```

Hope you all can help

Comment: Your button depends on the value of `selectedRow`, but nothing in your code sample modifies it. How do you plan to associate your selection model and the mentioned variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delete button is disabled when `selectedRow` is falsy. You'll need a function to update that variable when the checkbox is checked. In your `TableBasicExample` component you need to add a method:

```js
export class TableBasicExample {
  selectedRow: any;
  selection = new SelectionModel<PeriodicElement>(true, []);
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

  deleteUser(){
    console.log(this.selectedRow)
  }

  checkBoxSelected(row: number) {
    this.selectedRow = row;
    console.log(this.selectedRow);
  }
}
```

Then update your template accordingly:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [ngStyle]="{'display': 'none'}"> No. </th>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-radio-button
        (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" 
        (change)="checkBoxSelected(row)" <!-- HERE is the change -->
        [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
      </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

[Updated DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-yt5z7t)

Comment: But how to enable button?

Comment: Try to run the code, the button already is already checking for the `selectedRow` value. It will update dynamically based on the value of `selectedRow`

Comment: Also there is some weird CSS you're using for the checkbox which requires it to be double clicked and also jumps. But that is a separate issue

Answer (score 2):

.html

```
 <mat-radio-button (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" 
                   (change)="$event ? selection.select(row) : null ;
                   callIt(row)"  <-- here is the change --->
                   [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
 </mat-radio-button>
```

.ts file

```
export class TableBasicExample {
  selectedRow= false;
  selection = new SelectionModel<PeriodicElement>(true, []);
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

 callIt(row){
    this.selectedRow = true
    console.log(row)
  }
  deleteUser(){
    console.log(this.selectedRow)
  }
}
```

[DEMO here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-affkgw?file=app/table-basic-example.ts)

Comment: call the function callIt() and change the value of this.selectedRow. simple